# FeignException ServiceUnavailable: Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service match-result-service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I fail to understand, nor find any explanation about how can I fix the exception in subject.

This is the main code I use:

### Eureka Server

application:

```
...
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class BbSimApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BbSimApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yml:

```
server.port : 8088

spring: 
    application: 
        name : bbsim-discovery-server

eureka:
    server:
        evictionIntervalTimerInMs: 3000
        response-cache-update-interval-ms: 3000
        wait-time-in-ms-when-sync-empty: 0
        peer-node-read-timeout-ms : 10000
    client:
        registerWithEureka: false
        fetchRegistry: false
        service-url: 
            defaultZone: http://localhost:${server.port}/eureka
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

    @Autowired private WebService webService;

    @GetMapping("/matchresultbyids")
    public MatchStats matchResult(@RequestParam Long homeId, @RequestParam Long awayId){

        return webService.matchResult(homeId, awayId);
    }
}
```

---

### Manager Service

application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class BBSimManagerServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BBSimManagerServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.yaml:

```
server.port: 9903

spring:
    application.name: bbsim-manager-service
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8088/eureka}
            registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 1
            # register-with-eureka: true
            # fetch-registry: true
    instance:
        leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
```

Client interface:

```
@FeignClient("match-result-service")
public interface MatchResultClient {

    @GetMapping("/matchresultbyids")
    MatchStats getMatchResult();
}
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class BbsimManagerController {
    
    @Autowired
    MatchResultClient matchStatsClient;
 
    @GetMapping("/matchresultbyids")
    public MatchStats matchResult(){

        return matchStatsClient.getMatchResult();
    }
}
```

---

### MatchResult Service

application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MatchResultServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MatchResultServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.yml:

```
server.port: 9901

spring:
    application:
        name: match-result-service
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://localhost:8088/eureka/
            registryFetchIntervalSeconds: 1
            instance:
                leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

    @Autowired private WebService webService;

    @GetMapping("/matchresultbyids")
    public MatchStats matchResult(){

        return webService.matchResult();
    }
}
```

[image]

When I try to execute:

> http://localhost:9903/matchresultbyids

I get the exception:

```
o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is feign.FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: [503] during [GET] to [http://match-result-service/matchresultbyids?homeId=0&awayId=1] [MatchResultClient#getMatchResult()]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service match-result-service]] with root cause

feign.FeignException$ServiceUnavailable: [503] during [GET] to [http://match-result-service/matchresultbyids?homeId=0&awayId=1] [MatchResultClient#getMatchResult()]: [Load balancer does not contain an instance for the service match-result-service]
```

Can you advise me what is wrong and how to fix it?

Thank you all.

Comment: Do you try going to `localhost:8088`, and sure that `match-result-service` instance registered successfully on Eureka or not?

Comment: @NguaCon Please see added image in question.

Comment: Do you try call `http://localhost:9901/matchresultbyids ` directly to ensure available? Error said that service unavailable.

Comment: @dushkin if the problem persists, please create a GitHub issue with a link to a sample that reproduces the issue - will try debugging it.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue

Comment: @Shardendu I admit I do not remember. I guess no - otherwise I would update here. Sorry...

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to OpenFeign [bug](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/milestone/46?closed=1). You can try to upgrade it to the version  >= v3.0.6.
If you use spring-cloud-dependencies the version >= v2020.0.5 should be also ok.